# Can I showcase the games I make with Unreal Engine on my website?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I know this is possible with Unity3D games using OpenGL. I am just looking for confirmation here that it will be possible for me to do this with Unreal Engine games coded in C++.

I am interested in this because I plan to showcase them on my website for job interviews, so a definite answer would be very much appreciated!

Edit: **To clarify, I am interested in knowing whether**

1) It is possible to somehow put my games on my website so that whoever visits the website could play them if they so wish.

2) Any licensing issues that could arise from putting my games on my website considering that I am using the free version of UE and I don't plan to monetize those games

Comment: You question is about licensing?

Comment: Well, I guess I am interested in both its feasibility, and about licensing.

Comment: Are you asking about playing your game live on your website via webgl? It's unclear what aspect you're talking about.

Comment: Yes, ideally I would like whoever visits my website to be able to play the game I created.

Comment: 1. What have you tried doing? Generally speaking the Unreal Engine is capable of creating browser based games (as described in [the official documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Platforms/HTML5/index.html)), but the hosting of it is up to you, not the engine.
2. There is no "free version" of Unreal Engine, the license is very precise about how it works (and at what point you have to pay), so read it carefully.

Comment: How about adding game video?

Comment: I don't think that would provide a good enough proof that I made the video game if I just record myself playing

Comment: I agree with you @AlwaysLearning, publishing your game demonstrates your ability to deliver, and to take care of these sorts of important things. Publishing some source code on Github is also a very good idea to help show how you work (code, but also source control knowledge, commit messages and a descent README)

Answer (score 3):

You can definitely make games with Unreal Engine 4 using Blueprints and C++, and [package them in HTML5/JavaScript/WebGL](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Platforms/HTML5/index.html) using WebAssembly (replacing Asm.js in UE4.18).
You then have to put them on a webserver, be ready to spend some hours making this part works as it requires some configuration that depends on the web server you use (and is using some brand new rapidly evolving technologies)

On the License part of things, you need to pay 5% of your gross revenues (royalties) after some few thousands dollars by quarter.
So if your game is free, then you are free to publish and give them freely without anything to declare or pay.

Edit: From the [Unreal Engine EULA FAQ](https://www.unrealengine.com/en-US/faq):

> How much do I have to pay for Unreal Engine 4?
>
> > UE4 is free to use, with a 5% royalty on gross product revenue after the first $3,000 per game per calendar quarter from commercial products. Read the EULA FAQ for more details.
>
> Are any revenue sources royalty-free?
>
> > Yes! The following revenue sources are royalty-free:
> >
> > - [...]
> > - Truly free games and apps (with no associated revenue).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, perhaps can you accept the answer, or add some comments if it's still not clear or not what you are looking at?